# Fastest method to get the screenshot image of an external webpage

Tags: php, screenshot

Hi,

I want to get the screenshot of several pages and display them on my website. As of now, I am using the method below:

```
<?php

$site = $screenurl;

$image = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=$site&screenshot=true");
$image = json_decode($image, true); 
$image = $image['screenshot']['data'];
$image = str_replace(array('_','-'),array('/','+'),$image); 

echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,".$image."\" alt=\"\">";
?>
```

but with 10 or more images per page, this method takes FOREVER to load them all or it wont even load them at all because it times out. I would like to know a more effective, optimized and faster way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: there are webpage thumbnail APIs you can use for this purpose, or you could create your own using nodejs / phantomjs.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a little more? Where can I find those thumbnail APIs other than Google?

Comment: just one of many:  https://thumbnail.ws/
or the phantomjs way:  http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but PHP's built-in (PHP >= 5.2.2) `imagegrabscreen` function is capable of returning an image resource containing a screenshot of the whole screen. It is sort of picky, though, from what I understand (never used it myself), requiring it to be run on a Windows system and ["allow Apache service to interact with the desktop"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php#82630). These documentation pages could be helpful:
[`imagegrabscreen` Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php) 
[`imagegrabwindow` Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabwindow.php)

Comment: I know the function but that only works on Windows so if my server is Linux which most likely it is, it wont work.

Comment: Darn, just edited that in as you commented that. I'm unaware of any other ways, then, unfortunately.